# Backbone Model Sync() and $.mockjax()

Tags: backbone.js, mockjax

I'm working on porting the UI of an existing application from GWT to Backbone. The backend stays the same. All requests in the backend are handled by a single endpoint. URL-encoded parameters determine what the response should be. For instance:

```
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getDashboard&object=dash&id=2
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getDashboard&object=dash&id=3
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=saveDashboard&object=dash&id=1 ... {json}
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getUser&object=user
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=createUser&object=user ... {json}
http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getUserPermissions&object=user
```

Don't ask who devised this scheme =P.. Now, I have to design Backbone Models / Collections to connect to this endpoint and use mockjax to simulate the ajax calls as well.. So I have two questions now.

1. How do I create mock calls for this in `mockjax`? Using something like follows works fine.. But requires the precise order of parameters in URL.. `mockjax`'s documentation states parameters can be matched with `data: { key: value }` hash.. But this doesn't work for me.. Can someone guide me further on this?

   ```
   $.mockjax({
       url: http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getDashboard&object=dash&id=2,
       responseText: { ... }
   });
   ```
2. How should the models be coded such that, for instance, DashboardModel accesses `http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getDashboard&object=dash&id=3` when fetched and `http://localhost/adminNPS?request=saveDashboard&object=dash&id=3` when saving..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to matching the query parameters using the `data` option, this is a [documented bug in Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/123). Basically, the request matcher only works with data objects on the `$.ajax()` call, not query strings.

That said, there are two ways you could handle this:

1) you could use the [regex version of the `url` matcher](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax#step-1-define-the-url):

```
$.mockjax({
  url: /adminNPS?request=[^&]+&object=[^&]+&id=[0-9]+/i, // tweak to your needs
  ...
});
```

2) or you could use the [fully custom matching ability](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax#dynamically-generating-mock-definitions) by passing in a function:

```
$.mockjax(function(settings) {
  // examine `settings.url` which would be something like:
  // http://localhost/adminNPS?request=getDashboard&object=dash&id=2

  var q = settings.url.split('?')[1].split('&');
  var data = {}; // will be a hash of the query data
  for (var i=0, l=q.length; i<l; ++i) {
    data[q[i].split('=')[0]] = q[i].split('=')[1];
  }

  // Now you can look at the `data` object to do your matching

  if ( /* the URL matches what you want */ ) {
    return {
      response: function () {
        this.responseText = { ... }; /* whatever you want the response to be */
      }
    };
  }
  return; // no match
});
```

*Updated to show how you might investigate the query string...*

Comment: Thanks for the response jakerella. However the core argument still remains unaddressed. What SINGLE regex can possibly match AND capture the `request` and `object` variable values in both these urls. `/adminNPS?request=abc&object=xyz` and `/adminNPS?object=xyz&request=abc`.

Comment: The only solutions I have are: 1. Define multiple regex permutations and test for each of them (request > object and object > request). 2. Define single regex and ensure the query string contains parameters in a fixed order only.

Comment: Actually, if you use option (2) in my answer you could then extract the entire query string from the url, split it on the `&`, and then look at each parameter to determine if you have a match. I can update the code to show that...

Comment: agreed.. that certainly is one way.. just as multiple regex are.. but in my opinion, quite a bit messy.. the ideal situation in my case would be a single regex that captures all the parameters regardless of the order they appear in.. however i think that this may be wishful thinking and probably no regex exists that can do this.. in which case, your answer turns out to be the next best option.. and hence correct.. :)

Comment: There is a regex that can do this... it's just super messy, and possibly not very maintainable. Basically you'd have to account for each option in each position, or do lookbehind/lookahead matching. Again, possible, but probably less than ideal.

Comment: I was afraid so too. Thanks. :)